# how to remove css class dynamically in angular

Tags: angular

I write this

```
var DigitalIdSelected = 
      document.getElementById('DigitalID').classList.remove('selectDigitalId');
```

but it is not working for me my element is in array i bind images from database and i have to check which item has applied "selectedId" class if it is applied then i have to remove that class

Answer (score 1):

You should really not access DOM-elements by using getElementById (to adjust css classes), instead you should:

In Angular, use:

`[ngClass]` or `[class.DigitalId]` property bindings

and in Angular.js, use:

`ng-class`-directive

Since you've tagged your question with both Angular, as well as Angular.js, I'm not sure which one you're using

Comment: i am using angular 11 and i bind dynamic images to img tag and i have to check particular class is applied on item or not if applied then i have to remove from all the items that class